# filter list with any combination of fields in java using if statement

Tags: java, list, if-statement, filter

Suppose that we have a class like Person

**Person.java**

```
public class Person{

    String lastName;
    String code;
    String name;
    int age;

    public Person(String lastName, String code, String name, int age) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.code = code;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Person(%s,%s,%s,%s)", name, lastName, code, age);
    }


}
```

suppose there is another class that creates a list of Person

**FilterList.java**

```
public class FilterList {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Person> list = Arrays.asList(
            new Person("Oscar", "ali soltani", "15-01", 0x20),
            new Person("Reyes", "javan", "16-01", 0x30),
            new Person("Java", "javan", "18-01", 20),
            new Person("hamid", "javan", "18-01", 20)
    );

    int age = 0 ;
    String name = "";
    String code = "";
    String lname = "javan";
    for (Person p : list) {
        if (((Integer.toString(age).isEmpty() || age ==0) ? true :p.getAge() == age) 
                && (code.isEmpty() ? true : p.getCode().equals(code)) 
                &&(lname.isEmpty() ? true :p.getLastName().equals(lname))  && 
                (name.isEmpty() ? true :p.getName().equals(name))  ) {
            System.out.println(p);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Again, Suppose that we want to filter the list of Person by each field or any combinations of fields, e.g. if the field name is available we get the result such as every person whose name equals the given name, for example,

```
name = "ali";
```

So, You should write such code like :

```
   for (Person p : list) {
        if(p.getName().equals(name)){
            System.out.println(p);
        }
    }
```

Therefore the output goes like this :

```
Person(hamid,javan,18-01,20)
```

If you want to filter the list on any field you should write the same code, using **if** statement and suitable getter method and parameter to check the equality. there are four fields in the class **Person** we should write four if statements for each one.
On the other hand, if you want to filter the list on any combinations of field you should write as before. Remarkable that if there are 4 fields in the class **Person** we should write 4! different if like the code below to support every combination of fields :

```
        for (Person p : list) {
        if(p.getName().equals(name)){ // filter on name
            System.out.println(p);
        } else if(p.getLastName().equals(lname)){ //filter on lastname
            System.out.println(p);
        } else if(){ // rest of the field same as above
            .
            .
            .

        }else if(p.getName().equals(name) && p.getLastName().equals(lname)){
                //filter on name and lastname
                System.out.println(p);
        }
        // rest of the code for other combinations
        .
        .
        .
        else if(p.getName().equals(name) && 
                p.getLastName().equals(lname) && 
                p.getCode().equals(code) &&
                p.getAge() == age){
                //filter on all fields
                System.out.println(p);
        }
    }
```

For the conditions with the dozens of fields, this would be very difficult and prone to errors, N! different states for the class with N fields.

I solved this problem by using  **? : operator** combining it with the if statement and **filter the list with any combination of filed only with one if**

```
 for (Person p : list) {
        if (((Integer.toString(age).isEmpty() || age ==0) ? true :p.getAge() == age) 
                && (code.isEmpty() ? true : p.getCode().equals(code)) 
                &&(lname.isEmpty() ? true :p.getLastName().equals(lname))  && 
                (name.isEmpty() ? true :p.getName().equals(name))  ) {
            System.out.println(p);
        }
    }
```

and it work perfectly.

Is there any better way to answer this question ?

Comment: "I solved this problem by using `? :` operator" You didn't solve any problems by writing that condition like that!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stackoverflow is not the place for questions about code which is working correctly. Please post your question on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead :)

Comment: I asked for better solution

Comment: Exactly. "Better solution" is not a question appropriate for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

You could override `equals` (if you are pretty good with one rule) or you can do it more flexible creating special [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)s for your object. Just remember comparator returns -1, 0, 1. So you should to use one via bridge, which converts 0 -> true and [-1, 1] -> false. In this implementation way you'll have separate logic of comparing objects by special rules (overriding `equals` you can cover only single rule case).

To cove your needs with lot of special if handlers you could use pattern [chain of responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern). If you use one do not forget to break the chain if condition already handled and others should not be considered.

Disadvantage of creating different rules per case is code increase, but benefit is flexible solution. You have good instrument to change the chain service. You can use this chain from anywhere or create another chain using existing `rules`. General code part will not be changed if you need improve your `conditions`. The chain can be tested in separate isolated way.

If you do not know GoF design patterns I recommend you check some information on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673841/examples-of-gof-design-patterns-in-javas-core-libraries) (very good examples and explanations), on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns).

Answer (score 0):

Try Java 8 Stream and Filters, like below:

```
List<Person> list = new ArrayList<>();
Person p1 = new Person("Mehdi");
Person p2 = new Person("Mark");
Person p3 = new Person("Cris");
list.add(p1);list.add(p2);list.add(p3);

List<Person> filteredList = list.stream().filter(member -> "Mehdi".equals(member.name)).collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(filteredList.get(0).name);
```